# Connect radial input and text input

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-model

I have form with radial buttons but the last one is a combination of radial button and text input. I want to somehow connect the two inputs. User should not be able to input the text before clicking the radial button next to it. Also when user starts to write text I wanna stop the radial button checked indication from disappearing. If user clicks some other radial button the text field should empty itself.

```
<label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" name="religion" value="noSay" ng-model="$ctrl.diversityTest.religion">Prefer not to say
</label>

<label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" name="religion" value="{{$ctrl.diversityTest.religion}}"> Any other religion or beliefe:
  <div>
     Please write in: <input ng-keyup="$ctrl.diversityTest.religion = $ctrl.diversityTest.temp" class="input-material" type="text" name="religion" ng-model="$ctrl.diversityTest.temp">
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.$ctrl = {};
  $scope.$ctrl.diversityTest = {};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio"  ng-click="$ctrl.diversityTest.temp='';$ctrl.diversityTest.otherReligionRadio='';" name="religion" value="noSay" ng-model="$ctrl.diversityTest.religion">Prefer not to say
</label>

    <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="radio" name="religion" value="Other_religion" ng-model="$ctrl.diversityTest.otherReligionRadio" > Any other religion or beliefe:
  <div>
     Please write in: <input class="input-material" type="text" ng-disabled="!($ctrl.diversityTest.otherReligionRadio)" ng-keyup="$ctrl.diversityTest.religion = $ctrl.diversityTest.temp"  name="religion" ng-model="$ctrl.diversityTest.temp">
  </div>
</label>

    <br> Religion : {{$ctrl.diversityTest.religion}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for your effort but it seems there are some bugs in this. If I click other religion and start typing, but then click Prefer not to say I can still continue typing. Also, this is another model, I need just one religion model.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk let me fix it.

Comment: sorry. other religion model was left in my example above, I edited it now to just religion

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. This is exactly what I wanted. I just pulled out temp ng-models out of diversityTest object and it works as I need it to. Can I somehow tag you for all my questions :p